# Yii2: How can I create constructor in a controller?

Tags: yii2

How can I create a constructor in a Yii2 controller? I am trying to find out what exactly is the `$id` `$module` and `$config = []` in the `parent::__construct` arguments.

```
public function __construct($id, $module, $config = [])
{
    $this->id = $id;
    $this->module = $module;
    parent::__construct($config);
}
```

I would appreciate a working example.

Comment: I don't understand. If you want do something on start, create a `init()` function.

Comment: @joaner I realize in theory they are both one and the same with their functionality but how can I do it using `__construct`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There shouldn't be anything wrong with

```
public function __construct($id, $module, $config = [])
{
    \yii\helpers\VarDumper::dump([$id, $module, $config]);
    parent::__construct($id, $module, $config);
}
```

if the goal is to investigate what happens there.

For production it is better to stick to overriding `init` method and use `$this->id` and `$this->module` there if needed. That's where the framework [expects initialization code to be placed](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-object.html):

> It is recommended that you perform object initialization
>   in the init() method because at that stage, the object configuration
>   is already applied.

Answer (score 1):

**in yii2 you can use init function rather than constructor function**

> It's recommended to use init(), you can found it a lot in the
>   extensions, but in some cases, you should use __construct(). you can
>   find it [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-object.html).
>
> construct runs on a new instance, and then it calls the init()
>   function which calls all the default values and functions in the class
>   to set. so using init() is more easily and safely and do the same work as __construct() function

```
 public function init() {
    your code
}
```

Comment: While this answer may be correct. Code only answers are rarely helpful. Please comment your code and provide an explanation for how this code solves the problem.

Comment: thanks i add more informations about init() function what it used for and why we should use it rather than the  constructor function

Comment: Vote up, because with explanation, your answer is actually helpful.